# Continuous integration with Android [Codeship]

Tags: android, build, jenkins, codeship

I have an Android app source code which uses
1 Android SDK (Obviously)
2 Robolectric (for unit tests)
3 Gradle (for build process)

The problem encounter while trying to use the other build process is that I'm required go into my repo and fetch the Android SDK every time and extract it. Then, clean and run my tests and jacocoTestReport. This takes time not due to the number of tests but, due to the amount of time spent fetching Android SDK and extracting. On my local machine, I can use Jenkins with Android plugin.

My question: 
Am I doing it right? 
Is there an easier way around this to reduce the build time so that I can put a POST hook over my repo for it to run better (Only take up time required to run tests and reports).

Comment: Why do you fetch `Android SDK` every time? `Jenkins`(and other CI servers) has configurable environment variable which refers to the `Android SDK` local folder.

Comment: I wasa codeship. Which was a automated build environment for web applications. Supposedly not a very good choice for mobile applications.
I have moved over to hosted jenkins server with installing Android on it and CI-ing over it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Codeship doesn't support Android in this moment. But I think they are working on it

Comment: Thanks, yes Codeship is mostly for web environments rather than Android or mobile.

Answer (score 1):

With CodeShip Pro you can utilize an Android Docker image to do builds, but this is not *officially* supported.

https://documentation.codeship.com/general/about/mobile-support/